# Using Vim with Vifm

Tags: buffers, terminal

When I open a file in Vifm and edit it with Vim is it possible to tab back to Vifm without closing the file? Or is it possible to use Vifm inside Vim to open files?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [How to open new files in a same Vim instance from my file manager or from command-line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588202)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not exactly what you want... But there's a Vim plug-in [vim/vifm.vim](https://github.com/vifm/vifm.vim/blob/2b4f42cc3142b163de17971a3ebfc1e6bad3da3e/doc/plugin/vifm-plugin.txt) that adds new Vim commands `:Vifm` (or `:EditVifm`), `:SplitVifm`, `:TabVifm`, etc. which use Vifm as a file picker from inside Vim. See the plug-in's [help](https://github.com/vifm/vifm.vim/blob/2b4f42cc3142b163de17971a3ebfc1e6bad3da3e/doc/plugin/vifm-plugin.txt) for more details on what it provides.

It won't really keep Vifm around after opening the file, so not sure this is exactly what you have in mind...

---

Another possibility would be to spawn Vifm inside a Vim `:terminal` and then use the Vim [terminal API](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-api) to have it request Vim to open specific files. I think it should be possible to do so with a `filetype` hook in Vifm that prints the magic escape that the Vim terminal will recognize. Not sure if something like that already exists. (I'm not really a Vifm user myself.)

Comment: I think that’s exactly what the vifm plugin does :)